# what would be the SQL to execute this ? i want to group by a column with a specific condition

Tags: sql

I have a table (`EXPENSE`) like this:

| year | month | date | amount | split | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 2 | 21 | 100 | Y | A |
| 2020 | 2 | 1 | 100 | Y | A |
| 2020 | 2 | 2 | 100 | N | A |
| 2020 | 3 | 21 | 100 | Y | A |
| 2020 | 3 | 23 | 100 | Y | B |
| 2020 | 3 | 14 | 100 | Y | A |

I want to write a SQL query that will do a group by on year, month, split and type and return `sum(amount)` with condition that when split=Y date should be taken as 31 irrespective of month.

I wrote this SQL:

```
select 
    year,
    month,
    case 
        when split = 'Y' then 31 
        else date 
    end,
    sum(amount),
    split,
    type
from 
    EXPENSE
group by
    year, month, split, type
```

Expected result:

| year | month | date | amount | split | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 2 | 31 | 200 | Y | A |
| 2020 | 2 | 2 | 100 | N | A |
| 2020 | 3 | 31 | 200 | Y | A |
| 2020 | 3 | 23 | 100 | Y | B |

but I'm getting an error:

> An expression starting with "date" specified in SELECT clause, HAVING
> clause, or ORDER BY clause is not specified in GROUP BY clause.

I don't want to group by with date unless split = Y.

Comment: Either MySQL or SQL Server. Not both. Select one and remove wrong tag.

Comment: Including the column date or the expressions in the GROUP BY clause that are in the SELECT clause

Comment: For what it's worth, the same answer will apply to [tag:mysql], [tag:sql-server], and [tag:postgresql].    https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rLXRryhgn3J7HdYDGPPnC3/0

Comment: Please mention your dbms with version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just repeat the expression for the `group by`:

```
select year, month,
       (case when split = 'Y' then 31 else date end),
       sum(amount), split, type
from EXPENSE
group by year, month, (case when split='Y' then 31 else date end),
         split, type;
```

Comment: thanks, it worked. makes sense to add case in group by as well.